# Mapping server errors with RESTKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I use RESTKit successfully to access a Web service. But I have problems to map server errors (like 404, 403...) to RESTKit's standard RKErrorMessage class. Let's say I get the following JSON response from my service together with a 403 status code:

```
{"errors":{"message":"Some error message"}}
```

In my iOS application I try to map the errors with the help of:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping
   attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"message" toKeyPath:@"message"]];

statusCodes4xx = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError);

errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:notecardMapping 
                     pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"errors" statusCodes:statusCodes4xx];
```

But all I get is an error from RESTKit:

```
Failed mapping operation: No mappable values found for any of the attributes or relationship mappings
```

Where is my fault? Is it just a wrong path in the descriptor for example?

Comment: I think you want `@"errors.message"` as your key

Comment: also shouldn't it be `addAttributeMapping`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately "errors.message" doesn't work, too. My code is very similar to the described solution on the RESTKit website: [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). But they don't publish the according server response for their example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using `notecardMapping` instead of `errorMapping` in your response descriptor. Try this:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];

[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:@"errors.message"
                                                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[errorDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Indeed, should be errorMapping within the response descriptor. Furthermore "erors" as keyPath in the descriptor was actually enough. Many thanks!